# linux-image-extras Uninstalled

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers

I've uninstalled the linux-image-extras kernel by mistake, as I was trying to free up disk space. I later found out it's essential, as I couldn't use my keyboard or mouse after restarting. Is there any way I could reinstall it, without having to do a clean install of Ubuntu?

Comment: Most people usually have more than one kernel version. Reboot and at grub menu select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select an older kernel and hope one of them works. I'm not entirely sure that linux-image-extras is required after initramfs has created /boot files though...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I deleted all but one of them, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it the same - no keyboard - if you boot into rescue mode and drop into a shell?

Comment: Also, if you currently use a USB keyboard, you could try connecting a PS2 one, if possible and available, or vice versa.

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't have a PS2 keyboard neither :(

Comment: You should be able to boot a live CD, `chroot` into your installation and install the packages that way. Unfortunately I don't know how exactly to do that off the top of my head and I can't look it up right now for you. Google is your friend.